# Get a list of all checkboxes in a div using PLAIN JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, dom, xhtml

If the checkboxes were in a form, I would do:

```
document.getElementById(form_id).elements;
```

But if the checkboxes are in a

```
<div id="div_id">
```

then is it the same code?

Comment: Already did that but the answers are all with jquery.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.querySelectorAll('div#div_id input[type=checkbox]')
```